# File download based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, download, checkbox

I have a bunch of checkboxes which are linked to documents users can download. I have hacked away at some code at gotten to here.

So far the downloadChecked function works as intended, but I can't seem to get the makFrame function to run correctly. At the moment it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
function makeFrame( url ) 
{ 
ifrm = document.createElement( "IFRAME" ); 
ifrm.setAttribute( "style", "display:none;" ) ;
ifrm.setAttribute( "src", url ) ; 
ifrm.style.width = 0+"px"; 
ifrm.style.height = 0+"px"; 
document.body.appendChild( ifrm ) ; 
}  

function downloadChecked( )
{
for( i = 0 ; i < document.downloadform.elements.length ; i++ )
{
  foo = document.downloadform.elements[ i ] ;
  if( foo.type == "checkbox" && foo.checked == true )
  {
    makeFrame('somefile.do?command=download&fileid=' + foo.name );
  }
}
}
```

and the corresponding HTML

```
<form name="downloadform">
<input type="checkbox" name="file" id="file1"     
value="file source etc" />

<input type="checkbox" name="file" id="file2"     
value="file source etc" />

<input type="button" value="Download all" onClick="downloadChecked();" />
```

Comment: Check a developer / debugging tool for any errors. That will help us determine at which point your function fails. If you are using Firefox, you'll want to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). All recent mayor browsers including IE9+ have built in developer tools.

Comment: Does your download handler "somefile.do" set appropriate headers for your file?

Answer (score 0):

when you declare

```
ifrm = document.createElement( "IFRAME" );
```

inside the function, you are creating a global object. hence, everytime makeframe() is called, you are destroying the previous iframe.
Try:

```
  var ifrm = document.createElement( "IFRAME" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it still doesn't seem to work though

Comment: what exactly is the problem? no iframe is loaded? only one?

Comment: When I press the download button, it does nothing. Explorer seems to load for a split second then stops. No download prompt either for one or multiple selections

Comment: Is hiding it with display:hidden causing any issues?

Comment: Could the issue be with `makeFrame('somefile.do?command=download&fileid=' + foo.name );`

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe code is correct and should work. However in your downloadChecked  function you are appending foo.name as your fileid query string attribute which, with your current markup, will result in "&fileid=file". Assuming that you store fileid for your query string in the input's value attribute you might want to change "foo.name" to "foo.value"

Comment: Yes you are correct with that, and while I have now changed it to .value, I am still not getting any download prompt/message and nothing seems to be happening